# Folder auto sync when available

Tags: networking, sync, nas, network-drive

I'm searching for an application that gives me the possibility to "Sync" my folders (documents, photos, movies, desktop and so on) with my Network Drive on my Synology NAS. If I'm not home/when the Network Drive is not available), the application needs to "save" my changes and sync these when I'm back home (/when the Network Drive is available). Also, when I change something on my notebook and I'll start my desktop, these files need to begin sync'ed with my desktop.

Currently I have one desktop and one notebook, both with Ubuntu and connected to my NAS.

After a ton of searching I found some applications, like Rsync and Unison, but it seems these only sync manually and doesn't sync back (NAS > Desktop or NAS > Notebook).

Thanks,
Wouter0100

Comment: I didn't try it, but lsyncd seems what you are looking for, also judging to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15283061/1391444 . It seems well documted on the web and the man pages are quite clear.